# Censored Regression/Tobit: coefficients decrease drastically when non-normal distribution is assumed

Tags: r, normality-assumption, censoring, tobit-regression

I am trying to use a Tobit/ censored regression model to estimate the effect of a certain political condition on a tax. Our dependent variable is zero-inflated because in most of our observations this tax was not implemented. We tried to fit a standard Tobit model, but given our data is non-normal, we could not fully satisfy Tobit's assumption that the generalised residuals are normally distributed.

We therefore tried to fit a more generalised Tobit model assuming a student-t distribution with the help of the R package crch. The model fit in terms of log-likelihood increased substantially (much more than in the example below). However, all coefficients changed dramatically, decreasing by around 80-90% (similarly, but even a bit more than in the example below). I am very sorry when I am being naive, but this drastic change suprised me and I was wondering whether somebody knows why all coefficients decrease so much once the normality assumption is relaxed?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(AER)
library(crch)

# Generating sample data
y=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,168,0,241,225,159,89,49,5,43,19,12,31,15,    
0,0,0,28,0,31,0,0,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,0,0,22,0,21,33,24,167,0,0,0,0,
26,31,368,192,74,0,0,31,0,0,26,0,0,165,0,24,0,25,0,0,0,0,179,0,0,0,
36,14,31,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,199,0,0,0,0,0,18,48,0,40,0,0,0,0,0
,0,17,82,756,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

x=c(16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,11,18,
16,9,15,8,7,13,12,6,6,9,12,17,15,9,7,5,12,12,14,14,17,16,10,5,6,6,14,
17,17,14,17,14,9,11,9,8,12,10,9,17,5,13,10,16,10,9,9,8,14,10,9,10,
15,17,14,9,10,11,10,7,13,9,6,8,18,17,7,7,11,12,10,14,13,9,12,8,
10,4,9,19,10,14,13,17,7,11,6,10,8,11,8,8,12,16,4,2,8,11,8,3)

## Trying standard Tobit model...
model_t <- tobit(y~x, left=0, right = Inf)
shapiro.test(residuals(model_t, type="working")) # ... but assumption fails

# Resorting to a generalized censored regression model with crch
summary(model_t)
summary(model_crch <- crch(y~x,left=0))
summary(model_crch2 <- crch(y~x,dist="student",left=0))

shapiro.test(res1 <- residuals(model_crch, type = "quantile"))
shapiro.test(res2 <- residuals(model_crch2, type = "quantile"))
# When a student-t distribution is assumed, log-likelihood and normality of 
# residuals are becoming better, but somehow coefficients decrease drastically
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think the change in scale is responsible but I'm not seeing exactly how.  Does it help to know that the predicted values from the first and last models are perfectly correlated (though the two sets are on different scales), while the residuals from each model are not (*r* = .61).  Predicted value in model_crch2 = .23*predicted value in model_t + 6.311.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting hint! But also I can't figure out why the scale should change...

Comment: The crch documentation talked about scale-related matters.  In r, "?crch".

Comment: I am not so sure about that. It talks about the scale function, which allows the model to estimate the effect of one co-variate on the distribution of residuals. This is something different than the scale of the predictor / co-variate.

Comment: If you look at `plot(y ~ x)` you see that there are only relatively few non-zero observations and for a relatively small range of `x`. Hence, different models may attribute these to different probabilistic mechanisms (differences in slopes, differences in variances, or differences in kurtosis). Especially, the student-based model is very extreme: `crch(y ~ x, left = 0, dist = "student")` yields df = 1.138 which has really heavy tails. I wouldn't trust this model. In contrast `"logistic"` also differs from `"gaussian"` but not is at least "similar".